# angular-pouchdb: pouchDB is not defined or is not a function

Tags: angularjs, pouchdb

I've installed this library in my angular app : https://github.com/angular-pouchdb/angular-pouchdb (using `ionic add angular-pouchdb`).

But I get this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: pouchDB is not defined` when I tried to declare a factory that instanciates the database. See my code below.

Module injection in app.js:

```
angular.module('BoardLine', ['ionic', 'ngCookies', 'ui.unique', 'pouchdb', 'BoardLine.controllers', 'BoardLine.services', 'BoardLine.filters'])
```

Factory in services.js to make the database available everywhere in the app:

```
.factory('usersDatabase', [ function(pouchdb) {
    var usersDatabase = pouchDB('boardline_users');
    var remote = 'https://louisromain:bingin/*@louisromain.cloudant.com/boardline_users';
    var opts = {live: true,
                retry: true};
    usersDatabase.replicate.to(remote, opts);
    usersDatabase.replicate.from(remote, opts);
    //console.log(usersDatabase);
    return usersDatabase;
}])
```

Srcipt call in index.html:

```
<script src="lib/angular-pouchdb/angular-pouchdb.js"></script>
```

Nota: If I write `.factory('usersDatabase', [ function(pouchDB) {` instead (uppercase DB instead of lowercase db),
I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: pouchDB is not a function`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular-pouchdb depends on pouchdb, so this line is required in index.html :

```
<script src="lib/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check typo puchDB -> puchdb

> .factory('usersDatabase', [ function(**pouchdb**) {
>       var usersDatabase = **pouchDB**('boardline_users');

Comment: thanks, I put this `.factory('usersDatabase', [ function(pouchDB) {...` now, and I have a new error : `Uncaught TypeError: pouchDB is not a function`

Comment: You are welcome. The name of the Angular module is "pouchdb", (not puchDB) you should use exact name as defined in angular-pouchdb.js. Also make sure that the module code is loaded with your Angular script.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't see where I did the typo "puchdb" without the "o"... I searched in my question above, and in my code, and I didn't make this typo

Comment: Sorry for my typo in comment. And let me fix another misunderstanding. The name of the module is puchdb but the name of the main function is pouchDB. Can you provide your script details (for example your code in header section)

Comment: I really don't see where you see this 'puchdb'....  I added the <script> tag in my question, tell me if you need more

Comment: I made a typo in my comment as I mentioned last comment. I wrote puchdb instead of pouchdb. I created a jsfiddle and testing it. Will share the link soon.

Comment: I could not make it run with pouchdb in jsfiddle. Can you try to do console.log(pouchDB); to see what is loaded. And maybe you should try PouchDB instead of pouchDB. (One other fork is using this case) And how did you get the module. Did you downloaded from github or used bower?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91319/discussion-between-emir-and-louis).

Comment: Hi @emir, I got the module from this command `ionic add angular-pouchdb
`. I can't see anything from `console.log(pouchDB)` as there is this error for now. Maybe you should remove your answer in the meantime, don't you think ?